# What part of speech is "garden" in "The garden industry is blooming"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

I have a doubt about parts of speech. I was given this sentence by a teacher, “The garden industry is blooming”, and I was told to identify the part of speech of each word. I don’t know what part of speech “garden” belongs to? Is it an adjective?

Comment: I think it would help if you explained a little bit more why you are unsure whether "garden" is an adjective or something else.

Answer (score 2):

"Garden" is a noun. It is being used as an adjective, and it can be called an "attributive noun". It describes or limits the noun that follows it, "industry". The two words together make up a noun phrase.

See:  [Thoughtco attributive noun](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)

> In English grammar, an attributive noun is a noun that modifies another noun and functions as an adjective. Also known as a noun premodifier, a noun adjunct, and a converted adjective.

Also see: [VOA](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/everyday-grammar-when-nouns-act-like-adjectives/2998821.html)

> Everyday Grammar: When Nouns Act Like Adjectives