# As a deterrent tool or deterrence tool?

Tags: grammar

I chanced upon an article that mentioned "as a conventional *deterrence* tool". Shouldn't it be deterrent instead? Since deterrence is a noun while deterrent is an adjective?

> If does not, however, it will have profound implications for its
> potential combat power against Ukrainian forces in the coming weeks,
> and its value as a conventional deterrence tool against Western
> countries.

Comment: This article should help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What part of speech is "garden" in "The garden industry is blooming"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/282095/what-part-of-speech-is-garden-in-the-garden-industry-is-blooming)

Comment: Should this site be called "*Stack**ed** Exchange*" since "stack" is a noun?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the noun *deterrence* in  *deterrence tool* is fine.

As @MarcinManhatten has pointed out, a noun can be an attributive noun. An attribute noun acts like an adjective and modifies another noun after it.  A similar example is **deterrence cameras**.